# adb not detecting galaxy ace after flashing android 4.3 cyanogenmod

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

I flashed my samsung galaxy ace (S-5830) with cyanogensmod android 4.3. But now i can't find the appropriate ADB drivers. I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not realy used to this, but i think you need this information! (yes it works on my mac at school, but not on the windows pc) _Product ID: 0x685e_ and: _Vendor ID: 0x04e8  (Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.)_

Comment: Okay, so you need a driver for that combination, or to change the VID/PID which some other driver is looking for to that.  You may find more specific advice on Android.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to switch the device into **PTP mode** *(under Settings -> Storage -> USB Computer Connection and  manually select the connection mode...)* and connect to computer. Let it install, switch back to USB mode and plug in again.

Comment: this procedure works on Galaxy S2 GT-i9100, running cyanogen mod 10.2.